# How to point out the real answer when another was selected by the question's author?

Tags: discussion

I have created [a question](https://askubuntu.com/q/223557/47206) on how to have "synonyms" context menu in Libreoffice Writer. I was concerned mostly by British English so, a comment to this question was the correct answer. But in fact that answer already existed to a similar question specifically asking about English UK ([here](https://askubuntu.com/a/196117/47206)). Only that it was not the answer that was selected as definitive in that case, while the one selected doesn't in fact work (anymore). How to confirm and highlight what the correct answer is?

Comment: Just went though and did a bit of...cleanup. Cheers!

Comment: @Marco Ceppi: In cleaned up question I was asking about different languages, not just about British. Also, the case of synonyms for British involved a bug, and I guess that is a separate question/answer. I still need a general as well as detailed answer to the question: "how to have synonyms for different languages" - that is: French, German, Romanian, Spanish etc. For some languages the option is there just by adding languages in "Language Support", for others like French, you need a separate extension, for others this is not available either. But now that question is closed. I don't get it.

Comment: @Marco Ceppi: it is pretty clear to me that if two questions have a common answer, it doesn't mean that this answer is the definitive or the complete one for both, so it doesn't mean that the two questions are clones. The more particular one (related just to UK English) may become redundant if the more general one  gets a very detailed answer that would include UK English, but that is hardly a reason to close the one that is the most inclusive and possibly most useful. i was still expecting new answer there: what to do? create new questions on separate languages??

Comment: @Marco Ceppi: in this sense that  question should be closed but for a different reason: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5467/47206

Answer (score 5):

The best thing you can do is leave a comment on the incorrect answer indicating that it no longer works and vote up the correct answer. You could also leave a comment on the question for the OP - and he can verify that the new answer works and mark it as accepted if he is still around.

Comment: what about editing the answer, to add that info, instead of just a comment - when one has the privilege?

Answer (score 4):

Since the existing answer is just a link to another post that then links to some blog that is out of date, it's clearly incorrect.

As George indicates, a courtesy comment is nice, but at the end of the day if it's wrong, vote accordingly and the author will either fix it, or delete it.

Personally, I think the accepted answer is not that good even when it was correct. As for your original question we should mark that as a duplicate of the original and then just concentrate on making sure the correct content floats to the top.

Comment: maybe my question that relates to any different language is not a duplicate to the one that only asks for British synonyms. i just added an answer to mine regarding French and expect new answers for other languages