# What is preferable: specific/limited or general/inclusive questions?

Tags: discussion

I have created a general question ([Synonyms for different languages in LibreOffice Writer?](https://askubuntu.com/q/223557/47206)) that was closed as a duplicate of a very specific one ([How do I add English-UK thesaurus in LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/q/42850/47206)).

I think that the reason for this was that the one asking for multiple solution got an answer that was present in the specific one.

I do not think that this was a good reason because a more general question cannot be a duplicate of a more particular one: unless, of course the one that seems specific is **not** in fact so, and has a solution that is general. In a such case the question/answer that just looks specific could be easily edited in order to get a general form. But clearly this is not the case for the English-UK synonyms question/answer (for some languages the  synonyms option is there just by adding languages in "Language Support", for others, like French, you need a separate extension, and for others such extention is not available either - see this [partial answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/223999/47206)) .

But maybe general questions like that should be **closed and replaced with case-by-case questions** related to separate languages. They are either to be replaced by multiple specific ones, or they should **not** be closed as duplicate of others the domain of which they include.

What would be the correct approach?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience of any StackExchange website, be as specific as possible. The questions of mine that get downvoted are general questions. It is best to ask a specific question and state how it is different from all of the other questions, even if they are different. On StackExchange websites, it is difficult to ask an acceptable question. It takes weeks of practice and many downvotes before many users get used to StackExchange.